# How to configure email accounts like support@xyz.com or feedback@xyz.com on AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I registered my domain with godaddy.com. Want to use EC2 with SES to host my website on amazon web services.

On my website there would be few email accounts like support@xyz.com or feedback@xyz.com. How can I configure these email accounts on my SES server ( or my ec2 server ); so that I could receive any emails sent to these email addresses ( through some mail client like Outlook, Thunderbird)

Comment: Do you have any email accounts on this site?

Comment: What do you mean by that Robert ? Are you saying to host my those email addresses with godaddy.com itself ? Yes that could be one of the solution..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the answer I received from the AWS team via the AWS forum:

> Hello,
>
> I'm sorry to say that SES doesn't handle inbound email today. We are
>   an outbound email delivery service only. However, you could (with some
>   effort) set up a postfix server and a POP3 server on an EC2 instance,
>   get a static IP bound to that EC2 instance, and list that on your MX
>   records. It is a bit more of a challenge than using gmail.com for
>   example, but it would provide you what are looking for.
>
> Thanks, and please let me know if I can help further.
>
> Paolo

Comment: As an update, AWS SES now supports handling incoming email. See the announcement at: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/09/amazon-ses-now-supports-inbound-email/

Answer (score 4):

You can sign your domain up for free Google Apps. During the setup, Google will direct you to modify your domain's MX records in Godaddy in order to receive mail. Then you can use AWS SES to send mail and mail will be received by your domain's Gmail user.

Comment: Sadly those Google Apps accounts are no longer free.