# I am hosting my website on Amazon s3 and I need to setup email addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, hosting

How do I setup new email addresses if I am hosting my static website on Amazon s3?  I want something like info@mydomain.com and contact@mydomain.com.

I know there is that SES service, but that is more for sending out emails.

I can try using GoogleApps but I thought there should be a way to do it on Amazon since every other hosting service provides that service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure email accounts like support@xyz.com or feedback@xyz.com on AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640507/how-to-configure-email-accounts-like-supportxyz-com-or-feedbackxyz-com-on-aws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess setting up your own Mail Server to Receive mails would be a big task for you. I would suggest to look for options like

- Office 365 - Exchange Online - works at $4 / user / month
- Google Apps - works at $5 / user / month

Setting up and configuring those server is straight forward; you would need take care in the DNS Zone File configuration. If you are choosing Office 365 and your DNS provided is GoDaddy, they do all settings for you. There would be similar things for Google Apps as well, if not there is very good Tech. Support to assisting you.

PS : For sending mails alone you can simply use SES